# Submitting pyspark from Windows to VM standalone cluster returns: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: windows, apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark

I have a standalone cluster on a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu. I have 10 physical machines connected to this cluster. When running:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://{ip}:7077 examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

On the VM, where {ip} is the address of the master, the script executes without issue. When running:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master local[*] examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

From powershell or VS Code on the Windows machine, the script executes without issue. Essentially, the Windows machine and the VM are configured correctly to execute the spark-submit script for the pi.py example.

However, when submitting the example to the VM master from the Windows machine:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://{ip}:7077 examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

via powershell or VS code, I continually receive the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've tried adjusting the `PYSPARK_HOME` system variable from `python` to `C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe` on the Windows machine to no avail. My understanding is that after submission, the VM is not able to locate the folder location for python. Is that correct? And if so, how do I remedy the No such file or directory error?

**NOTES**

- I see the job in the queue on Spark UI in the VM so I know the job is being received
- I've also whitelisted the necessary ports on the firewall so the VM can communicate with the Windows machine
- `$echo $PYSPARK_PYTHON` on the VM returns `python3`

Comment: I got this sorted by renaming the python.exe in /usr/bin/ in the VM from `python3` to `python`